# SQL - использование процедур для SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server

В последнее время просматривал множество разных OpenSource проектов, с использованием SQL.
Во почти всех проектах заметил такую закономерность, использования процедур для разных запросов а ля `SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE`.

Заинтересовал вопрос, почему для таких операций используют процедуры, а не просто обычные прямые запросы, сгенерированные тем же MSSQL?

В чем преимущество процедур в данном контексте?

Comment: под процедурами вы имеете в виду хранимые процедуры?

Comment: @teran да, именно их

Comment: Думаю, это просто случайность, что на глаза попались именно такие проекты.

Comment: Во-первых, в процедуре можно реализовать комплексную логику, которую не реализуешь в одиночном запросе. Да, IUD это можно делать и в триггере, но процедура попроще сопровождается. Во-вторых, можно через процедуру организовать доступ к данным, к которым у текущей учётной записи доступа нет. В третьих, унификация (связано со вторым), и не приходится бояться кривого запроса, который положит сервер или покорёжит данные. Ну и ещё куча причин, в основном менее существенных.

Comment: @Akina не могли бы вы привести 2-3 примера из написаного вами в виде ответа, дабы лучше понимать суть, как такое может выглядить и каким образом оно осуществляется. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что именно непонятно-то?

Comment: да и в целом это  некоторый слой абстракции, о деталях реализации которого разработчикам клиентского ПО знать не обязательно.

Comment: @Akina второй и третий пункт как примеру, не являюсь профессионалом/знающим в SQL. Хотелось бы предотвратить такие запросы в будущем при разработки ПО.

Comment: П. 2. Свойства ХП могут задавать, что при выполнении ХП применяются права доступа к данным создателя ХП, а не вызывающего. Соответственно ХП может получить доступ к данным, к которым у вызывающего доступа нет. П. 3. Все запросы в ХП известны, проверены и отлажены. Код ХП должен проверить задаваемые в запросе параметры. Никакой самодеятельности. А что за запрос клиент может послать серверу, ежели напрямую - даже самая буйная фантазия не предскажет.

Answer (score 0):

Это правильный подход, если запрос выполняется не один раз.
Почитайте про использование параметризированных переменных.
Простыми словами в таких процедурах запрос уже разобран сервером БД и сохранен у себя.
Вы вызываете процедуру и передаете ей что-то, это что-то подставляется в  параметризированную переменную в запросе, и серверу остается только одно - сделать выборку.
Если же вы отсылаете серверу традиционный запрос, то сервер каждый раз его разбирает, строит план и так далее... Что увеличивает и время запроса, и потребление дополнительных ресурсов сервера. Где на промышленных серверах ресурсы принято беречь, и время запроса критично.

Comment: Если запрос выполняется не один раз, то его можно на уровне драйвера БД заранее подготовить, а потом много раз выполнять, не прибегая к процедурам. План выполнения зачастую зависит от параметров запроса. Кроме того внешнее приложение для критичных к скорости мест может само строить запрос исходя из текущих потребностей (например приходилось делать условия вроде "если X равен 278 то условие field=X писать в запрос как (field+0)=X, в иных случаях просто field=X", потому что именно для 278 стандартный план выполнения клал сервер). Так что процедуры ради скорости спорный подход

Comment: Еще один плюс. Когда вся логика работы с объектами БД зашита в хранимых процедурах, представлениях и функциях это также огромный плюс для его дальнейшего сопровождения. Крупные компании особенно финансовые нанимают SQL девелоперов которые сосредоточены именно на SQL и лучше понимают архитектуру БД чем обычный разработчик клиентского приложения.

Comment: Вот с этим я соглашусь. когда команда даже из нескольких человек, то слои абстракции позволяют кому то одному отвечать за то, что твориться в БД. А такой слой на хранимых процедурах позволяет жестко разграничить доступ. И я бы сказал, что это как раз один из основных плюсов, в отличии от того, что указано в самом ответе